# Facebook doesn't fire refresh event and Tampermonkey won't work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

So the problem is that script is working until I log in into facebook, then to fire the script I would have to refresh whole site manually.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Open Test
// @version 1.0
// @description Test
// @include     http://facebook.com/*
// @include     http://*.facebook.com/*
// @include     https://facebook.com/*
// @include     https://*.facebook.com/*
// @include     http://facebook.com/*/*
// @include     http://*.facebook.com/*/*
// @include     https://facebook.com/*/*
// @include     https://*.facebook.com/*/*
// @include     http://facebook.com/*/*/*
// @include     http://*.facebook.com/*/*/*
// @include     https://facebook.com/*/*/*
// @include     https://*.facebook.com/*/*/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

alert('Hello world!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `@include` is not working since it seems that some of them must match facebook login page, anyway you can try to use `@match` instead to keep the things clear since some of your `@includes` are doing the same, for example your are adding:

```
// @include     https://facebook.com/*
// @include     https://facebook.com/*/*
// @include     https://facebook.com/*/*/*
```

But with the first one is enough `// @include     https://facebook.com/*` since it already matches for example `https://facebook.com/example/path/other`.

So as I said to keep things clear you can try with `@match` as follows:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Open Test
// @version 1.0
// @description Test
// @match *://www.facebook.com/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

alert('Hello world!');
```

> In this case `@match *://www.facebook.com/*`: 
>   Match any URL with both schemes (http and https) in www.facebook.com.

Basically the difference between `@includes` and `@match` is that `@includes` allows regex, but in your case seems that this is not needed.

Here you can see more info on [how `@match` works.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

Comment: Thanks, I was checking the url by setInterval but your way seems better.

Comment: @stevenhawkingsbiggestfan nice to help you `:)`